# jQuery.ajax Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I'm gettin this error and have no idea why:

```
jQuery.ajax Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I am trying to parse some information about a customer to another file that is in the main directory of the FTP-Server called "pricealarm.php"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#pricealarm-fakeSubmit").click(function(){
      if (jQuery('input[name="pa[offer]"]').val().length > 0 && jQuery('input[name="pa[email]"').val().length > 0 && jQuery('input[name="pa[name]"').val().length > 0 && jQuery('input[name="c_mac"]').val().length > 2 ) {

        //Parsing der Eingegebenen Information in die Datenbank (eigentliches Prozedere in pricealarm.php)
        var parse = {
          currency: jQuery('input[name="pa[currency]"]').val(),
          price: jQuery('input[name="pa[price]"]').val(),
          offer: jQuery('input[name="pa[offer]"]').val(),
          email: jQuery('input[name="pa[email]"]').val(),
          phone: jQuery('input[name="pa[phone]"]').val(),
          name: jQuery('input[name="pa[name]"]').val(),
          product: jQuery('input[name="pa[product]"]').val(),
          variant: jQuery('input[name="pa[variant]"]').val(),
          productID: jQuery('input[name="pa[productID]"]').val(),
          oxArtID: jQuery('input[name="pa[oxArtID]"]').val(),
          shopID: jQuery('input[name="pa[shopID]"]').val() 
        };

        jQuery.ajax(
        {
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'pricealarm.php',
          data: parse,

          success: function() {console.info(parse) },

          error: function() {console.info('pricealarm couldnt parse the data')}
        });
        return false;
    }
    else{
      jQuery('#pricealarm-fakeSubmit')after('<span class="js-oxError_notEmpty">[{ oxmultilang ident="ERROR_MESSAGE_INPUT_NOTALLFIELDS" }]</span>');
    }         
    });
  });
</script>
```

EDIT: Updated code to fit suggestions. Still not working yet
EDIT2: found the error x.x

Comment: are you getting this error in php? in this case - show us that code

Comment: @k102 no this is a javascript error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error myself:

```
 else{
  jQuery('#pricealarm-fakeSubmit')after('<span class="js-oxError_notEmpty">[{ oxmultilang ident="ERROR_MESSAGE_INPUT_NOTALLFIELDS" }]</span>');
}
```

was missing a `.` before `after`

```
 else{
  jQuery('#pricealarm-fakeSubmit').after('<span class="js-oxError_notEmpty">[{ oxmultilang ident="ERROR_MESSAGE_INPUT_NOTALLFIELDS" }]</span>');
}
```

Comment: You're also missing closing brackets in expression in if statement `jQuery('input[name="pa[email]"')` should be `jQuery('input[name="pa[email]"]')`. Same for the expressions name and c_mac.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** I provided this answer before the entire code sample was posted. Some of it is still relevant.

---

I think you have incorrectly defined your callback functions. They should be a function object; as they are, they are executing right away. Try:

```
  jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'pricealarm.php',
      data: parse,
      success: function() {
          console.info(parse);
      },
      error: function() {
          console.info('pricealarm couldn`t parse the data');
      }
  });
```

Also, make sure you're using a browser that understands `console.info`. Alternatively -- and this is my personal preference -- use the new jQuery Promise methods for the callbacks:

```
  jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'pricealarm.php',
      data: parse,
  }).done(function() {
      console.info(parse);
  }).fail(function() {
      console.info('pricealarm couldn`t parse the data');
  });
```

And lastly, I'm not completely sure about this, but the backtick (`) in the error string might be causing issues. They're part of a templating syntax proposed in ECMAScript 6 that some browsers already support.

Comment: Sorry, it was not intended. It should be there!

Comment: Can you provide more context for your code? Show the full method in which it's running, where it exists in your page, etc.

Comment: @CORY i found the error. i was missin a `.` in the `else` statement

Comment: @zeropublix: Great! Also, you are missing a `]` in both selectors here `jQuery('input[name="pa[email]"').val().length > 0 && jQuery('input[name="pa[name]"')`.